# Wondering if my perception of the following highlighted terms is correct

Tags: word-meaning

> "An Garda Síochána is determined to protect **communities** from the potentially devastating impact of these drugs and firearms"
>   The senior officer said the operation had been "**highly targeted**" and had involved "**close co-operation**" with the Police Service of Northern Ireland.
>   (source: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-27087586)

Based on my perception, the word *communities* has to do with small groups in a society, such as youngsters at schools or on the streets, or even could refer to street kids. 
*Highly targeted* has to with targeting the most important figures in charge of an event. 
And in the last one, although I know the meaning of *cooperation*, I cannot understand why the writer has written it in a way as if it is an adjective!

Comment: *Communities* here could just as well be replaced by *people*, since the intention is obviously to protect *everybody*, not just some subgroups within society. Feasibly *communities* could allude to the particular subgroups who would be more likely to affected by drugs/firearms, but mostly it's just a political buzz-word here. *Highly-targeted* here means the operation had very specific targets. It's unspecified whether this refers to particular *people* (certain drug/gun dealers) or *objectives* (try to eliminate heroin, but don't bother about cannabis, for example).

Comment: Note that *co-operation* here is a ***noun***, not an adjective. There is nothing unusual about the cited usage.

Comment: A *community* is, etymologically, any group which has *common* identity or interests. As used here it means a geographic community—all the people who live in a given place and have a common interest in security, as opposed to the small groups of criminals and drug users who live among them. As FumbleFingers says, it is a political buzzword, but not I think a meaningless one.

Answer (score 1):

"Communities" can refer to any grouping of people. It could be people living in particular towns, people of a particular social class or ethnic background, or people of a particular age. Which groups of people are intended will need to be determined from context.

"Highly targeted" does not necessarily refer to targeting specific people; it means that the operation is very specific in its scope; that it intends to achieve very specific ends. For example: an advertising campaign might be "highly targeted" if it is intended to reach only a specific subset of the population.

"Co-operation" is a noun used as a noun here. Think of how the sentence would read if you replaced it with other nouns or other adjectives:

> The operation involved **danger.**

makes sense. But:

> The operation involved **dangerous.**

does not.

Here "cooperation with the Police Service" is a noun phrase, and works the same way as "danger" does in the first example.